# Redirect Cloud Page

Tags: ampscript

On form submit I want to redirect the user to a cloud page url.

When I use the  following code

```
%%=Redirect('whole cloud page url')=%%
```

On form submission, I get 500 error.

To test if my code is working:

```
 %%=Redirect('google.com')=%%
```

And this worked. Is there a different function for CloudPage URL Redirect?

Thanks

Comment: Is the cloud page working? Might be an issue with the form..500 errors usually indicate backend errors (SSJS or Ampscript)

Comment: Yes it’s working correctly. It’s just when I add redirect code, I get 500 error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the Cloud Page published? 
Did you use CloudPage ID, not URL?

Example: `%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(55555))=%%`

You can grab CloudPage ID from Cloud Page details.

[image]

Comment: I want to redirect to the cloud page once the form submits successfuly.

When I used 
 %%=Redirect('google.com')=%%
 
 I can see that on form submission the page is redirected to google.com.
 
 However when I used below 
 
 %%=Redirect(CloudPagesURL(4343))=%%
 or
 %%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(4343))=%%
 
 It showed 500 error.

Comment: As noted by Data_Kid earlier, this message can pop up when there is a script error on the page. Can you post the page on pastebin?

Comment: When I remove the the %%=Redirect(CloudPagesURL(4343))=%% or %%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(4343))=%%, there is no 500 error in the page. This means that that there is something wrong with Redirect Function, as its not working in cloud page.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a form do not use `RedirectTo()` function. `CloudPagesURL()` is sufficient.

```
<form action="%%=CloudPagesURL(YOURPAGEID)=%%" id="formID" method="POST">
```