# Error on redirecting to a CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I am getting the following error when clicking a button in an email:

> We cannot direct you to the requested web page at this time. Please
>   try again.

The button is linked to a CloudPage in the most common way, using CloudPagesURL: `%%=CloudPagesURL(337)=%%`. There is nothing unusual happening in the Cloud Page itself, just some simple AMPscript wrapped in a try/catch statement, so it should work no matter what. The Cloud Page has been published and works fine when accessed from the link inside Web Studio -- but, I think the error happens somewhere earlier and upon clicking the button, we don't even get to the Cloud Page.

This is not a VAWP link and it is not in any way connected to a SendLog, so it's not that.

The only thing that comes to my mind, is that it might have something to do with the custom subdomain that we use in the account - but I checked other Cloud Pages and they can be accessed from email without any errors.

Any clues what else could be causing this issue?

Comment: can you post your code? If memory serves me right you need to wrap the cloudpagesURL in a RedirecTo

Comment: `%%=CloudPagesURL(337)=%%` - it's as simple as that and I shouldn't have to wrap it in a RedirectTo, it's not dynamically pulled from a Data Extension

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/196197/redirect-cloud-page

Comment: or maybe the service is down

Comment: The redirectTo() wrapper for CloudPagesURL is mostly only needed if you have the WAC turned on. Does your CloudPage utilize direct personalization strings or attributes that are pulled from the source - e.g. the field `MemberLevel` that originally existed in the Sendable Data but has since been deleted? Wondering if this would have same issues as VAWP with rendering sendable data that is no longer there.

Comment: Hi @Gortonington - we don't have WAC enabled in the account and there are no parameters passed in the link, we use the generic CloudPagesURL with page ID. The CloudPage itself does a lookup to a DE, but the data is there -- and we don't even get to the cloud page, it seems to be stuck before that.

Comment: Have you tried going to the direct link shown inside the Cloudpage editor?

Comment: @Gortonington yes >> The Cloud Page has been published and works fine when accessed from the link inside Web Studio.

Comment: Excuse the dumb question, but have you verified that is the correct CloudPageID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Gortonington thank you for the hint, turns out that my colleague who created the email, used the ID visible in the URL of the Cloud Page in Web Studio, not the actual Page ID - now we have replaced it and it's working fine.

[image]

Conclusion: the error message is displayed when the Cloud Page with the ID that you are trying to redirect to doesn't exist.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out!